# Learning multiple output

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, neural-networks

Can you suggest me an algorithm and probably a real code for multiple output learning, where input of the model is vector of around 10 000 values and output is, for each input vector, an output vector of 1500 dimensions (so, it's kind of a big dataset)?

In my opinion neural network can handle this number of values, but what else?
Supervised SOM? Multi-class multikernel learning?

Any examples of the real world data model with the same type of learning (large multiple output?)

Any suggestions and opinions will be very valuable for me.

Update: Data example can be found here - http://pastebin.com/Z4E87d3d

Comment: Wait, is the output 1500 UNIQUE values?  Is this a regression problem or a classification problem.

Comment: yes, output is unique label that can have binary (0,1) or other values.

Comment: so output is 0 or 1, with a length of 1500?

Comment: there are two cases: (1) output is binary, (2) output is notbinary (positive integer numbers)

Comment: If it's not proprietary, can I ask what on earth you're doing with 1500 outputs? Just curious....

Comment: You should probably consider whether 10k instances is enough evidence to support 1500-dimensional output. The [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) applies here. Only if the outputs lie on a much simpler subspace than a 1500 dimensional space will you be able to learn anything useful. In that case it's probably easier to map the outputs into a simpler space, and learn that.

Comment: I think no one got the question. The guys is asking if there is a machine learning algorithm that can learn 10000 features (assume F1) to produce 1500 outputs (assume O1). So if we assume that we have an experiment that work as follows F1 has -> O1, F2 -> O2, F3 -> O3 , .... then can this be done using machine learning, if so how.
I wish I can help further

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like [structured SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_SVM) could be a good fit. It allows for interdependent outputs, and as long as you have the time to wait to fit the SVM it should work fine. You can also use the kernel trick to handle for nonlinearities of various kinds.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much every learning algorithm I know could handle a dataset with 10,000 rows.  Random Forests, SVMs, boosted trees, penalized linear models, knn, etc. etc.  I've fit all of these models on datasets of that size on a pretty standard laptop (4GB ram, core i5 processor).

You can start to hit computational limits on a dataset of that size when you start re-sampling and cross-validating to avoid over-fitting.

I guess the answer to your question is "How much time do you have?"  Maybe waiting a few hours to cross-validate a 10x10 grid of parameters is more than you can spare.

Here's some example code in R.  Input is a random matrix with 5 columns and 2000 rows (10000 values).  Output is a binary vector with 2000 values.  I tried a random forest, an SVM, a penalized linear model, a KNN model, and a neural network.  All the models fit the entire dataset in under 1.5 seconds.  Tuning the models using bootstrapped re-samples took up to ~2 minutes each (although some models were quicker).

Here's the code:

```
#Setup
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
set.seed(1)

#Generate an input matrix with 10,000 values
#2,000 rows, 5 columns
X <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(2000)))

#Construct Y using X
Y <- runif(1)*X[,1]*X[,2]^2+runif(1)*X[,3]/X[,4]

#Convert Y to binary
Y <- as.factor(ifelse(sign(Y)>0,'X1','X0'))

#Create bootstap samples for fitting models
library(caret)
tmp <- createResample(Y,times = 25)
myCtrl <- trainControl(method = "boot", index = tmp, timingSamps = 10)

#Fit models
RFmodel <- train(X,Y,method='rf',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=1)         #Random Forest
SVMmodel <- train(X,Y,method='svmRadial',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=3) #Support Vector Machine
GLMmodel <- train(X,Y,method='glmnet',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=10)   #Penalized linear model
KNNmodel <- train(X,Y,method='knn',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=10)      #Nearest-neighbors
NNmodel <- train(X,Y,method='nnet',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=3, trace = FALSE) #Neural network

#Assess re-sampled (out of sample) accuracy
resamps <- resamples(
        list(   RF = RFmodel,
                SVM = SVMmodel,
                GLMnet = GLMmodel,
                KNN = KNNmodel,
                NN = NNmodel
                ))
summary(resamps)
dotplot(resamps, metric = "Accuracy")

#Assess run-time (in seconds)
resamps$timings
```

And here's the results:

```
Accuracy :
         Min. 1st Qu. Median   Mean 3rd Qu.   Max.
RF     0.8972  0.9062 0.9261 0.9205  0.9280 0.9490
SVM    0.8313  0.8437 0.8527 0.8546  0.8634 0.8800
GLMnet 0.6613  0.6808 0.6862 0.6918  0.6995 0.7295
KNN    0.8158  0.8244 0.8344 0.8368  0.8492 0.8661
NN     0.7592  0.7943 0.8003 0.8047  0.8231 0.8352

Run Time (seconds):
       Everything FinalModel Prediction
RF          33.80       1.28       0.03
SVM        110.76       1.17       0.01
GLMnet     104.21       0.05       0.01
KNN         17.09       0.00       0.02
NN          76.51       0.51       0.00
```

As a graph:
[image: Acc.]

Comment: yep, a lot of algorithms can handle even more than 10 thousand values as model input, but what's about output?

Comment: @Vladimir Chupakhin So output is a vector of (0,1) with 10,000 values?  Almost every algorithm I can think of can handle that.

Comment: @Vladimir Chupakhin: I updated my answer with an example of 10000 values as input and 2000 values as output.

Comment: Thank's a lot! But in my case all of the label in the vector are connected. So the vector is not the vector of independent variable but dependent variable specific for every entry.

Comment: @Vladimir Chupakhin: I don't follow you.  Could you provide some example data?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Data example can be found here http://pastebin.com/Z4E87d3d

Comment: The input data can be treated as: binary and integer values

Comment: @Vladimir Chupakhin  If your data consists of a  set of X vectors and a set of Y vectors, all of the same length, and the problem is to predict Y given X, then the procedure I outlined is sufficient.

Comment: Length is not the same.

Comment: Then you're going to have to explain the structure of the problem.

Comment: Hello! I have checked the code you provided, but the problem that example you gave hae 1 output, I remake the results with several outputs and actually caret fails.

Comment: @Vladimir Chupakhin:  You need one model per output.

Comment: Zach - This looks great. Unfortunately I was unable to replicate your example for the penalized linear model. I left the question here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49455/errors-fitting-a-penalized-linear-model I was wondering if you knew what could be causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Partial Least Squares (PLS) Regression. There is variant of PLS (PLS-DA) which can also be used for binary outputs. Search online for PLS package

It can output multiple ouputs. And, with its matrix-operations it is very fast too.

PLS: [PLS R Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/index.html)
PLS-DA: [Some notes on PLS-DA (again within Caret, an R Package)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf)