# Errors fitting a Penalized Linear Model in R

Tags: r, classification, generalized-linear-model

I am trying to reproduce the results from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14773/2798) in CrossValidated with no luck. I keep getting an error when calling:

```
print("Fitting Penalized Linear Model")
GLMmodel <- train(X,Y,method='glmnet',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=10)
```

Here is the error:

```
[1] "Fitting Penalized Linear Model"
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows: 1264, 736"
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first
 50)
```

The full code is below:

```
#Setup
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
set.seed(1)

#Generate an input matrix with 10,000 values
#2,000 rows, 5 columns
X <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(2000)))

#Construct Y using X
Y <- runif(1)*X[,1]*X[,2]^2+runif(1)*X[,3]/X[,4]

#Convert Y to binary
Y <- as.factor(ifelse(sign(Y)>0,'X1','X0'))

#Create bootstrap samples for fitting models
library(caret)
print("Creating bootstrap samples")
tmp <- createResample(Y,times = 25)
myCtrl <- trainControl(method = "boot", index = tmp, timingSamps = 10)

#Fit models
print("Fitting Random Forests")
RFmodel <- train(X,Y,method='rf',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=1)            

print("Fitting SVM")
SVMmodel <- train(X,Y,method='svmRadial',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=3)

print("Fitting Penalized Linear Model")
GLMmodel <- train(X,Y,method='glmnet',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=10)

print("Fitting Nearest neighbors")
KNNmodel <- train(X,Y,method='knn',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=10)

print("Fitting Neural Network")
NNmodel <- train(X,Y,method='nnet',trControl=myCtrl,tuneLength=3, trace = FALSE)

#Assess re-sampled (out of sample) accuracy
print("Assessing re-sampled (OOB) accuracy")
resamps <- resamples(
        list(   RF = RFmodel,
                SVM = SVMmodel,
                GLMnet = GLMmodel,
                KNN = KNNmodel,
                NN = NNmodel
                ))
print("Summarizing resamps")
summary(resamps)

print("Plotting accuracy")
dotplot(resamps, metric = "Accuracy")

#Assess run-time (in seconds)
print("Assessing timings")
resamps$timings
```

I am relatively new to R so I can't tell what's wrong with that line. Did the package GLM change since the time of that post? Is this a possible bug with `GML`?

For reference. I am running the latest version of R `(2.15.2)` with the latest stable version of [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) `(5.15-052)`

Comment: The above code runs fine for me with `caret_5.15-052`, `glmnet_1.8-5`, `Matrix_1.0-10` and `R-2.15.2` on windows. I will try on my mac later this evening.  I just copied and pasted it into a fresh R session.  Are you doing the same?

Comment: Although, I have to admit I've seen `"arguments imply differing number of rows: ..."` a lot in my caret models recently, and had just chalked it up to sleep-deprivation.  If you figure out the conditions that cause the error, perhaps you'll isolate a bug.

Comment: Hi Zach, yes. I am doing the same. Hmm, I don't think I manually installed `glmnet` or `Matrix`. Are they needed by GLM and not by the other packages? I am surprised it didn't prompt me to install those packages.

Comment: The glmnet method for `caret` requires the `glmnet` package.  The `glmnet` package require `Matrix`.  They were probably both installed when you installed caret.  Type `sessionInfo()` to see which versions you are running, and upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the package [`glmnet`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html). The error message:

> ```
> Error in { : 
>   task 1 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows: 1264, 736"
> In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first
>  50)
> ```

misled me to think there was problem with the input, not that I was missing a package.