# Packages or libraries for multiple-output learning

Tags: r, python, caret

I have a learning problem from $X$ to $Y$ where:

- $X$ = $n$ input numeric vectors of $m$ dimensions
- $Y$ = $n$ output numeric vectors of $k$ dimensions

In other words:

[image]

I am hoping to collect a **list** of **R** packages or **Python** libraries for **multiple-output** problems  for classification and regression.

For example, do any of the learning methods in [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) support this functionality? What packages in general are available for this problem?

Comment: Are all $k$ elements of $Y$ numeric?

Comment: Sounds like a many-to-many neural network might be one option.

Comment: @curious_cat. They are numeric. I just updated the OP

Comment: Since I cannot comment, I am looking for a similar solution to my problem i.e. multiple output. Does anyone know of any packages in R which supports multi outputs? My two outputs have a significant covariance. I have been predicting them separately using multiregression, trees and random forests, but I wish to predict them together. I am aware that this is possible using PLS and ANN, but is there any package like caret which does the aforementioned in a faster, compact way?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend the following **resources** (for some of those, you would need to do some detective work, obviously). I agree with @Innuo that PLS regression and `pls` R package are worth the look.

**For Python:**

- [This part of the curated list](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#python-general-purpose);
- also [this part of the same list](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#python-data-analysis);
- [this page from the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-multioutput).

**For R:**

- [This part of the same list](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#r-general-purpose);
- [CRAN Task View: Machine Learning & Statistical Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html).

I think that the following resources might also be quite helpful: [this relevant discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14761/31372) on CV, [this technical report](http://cbcl.mit.edu/publications/ai-publications/2011/MIT-CSAIL-TR-2011-004.pdf) on multi-output learning via spectral filtering, [this page](http://people.tuebingen.mpg.de/fdinuzzo/okl.html) on Output Kernel Learning, and [this excellent tutorial](http://www.ngdata.com/knowledge-base/icml-2013-tutorial-multi-target-prediction) on multi-target prediction.

Answer (score 3):

I know of the *PLS* R-package, which support multi-response regression. See "[The pls Package: Principal Component and Partial Least Squares Regression in R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v18/i02/)", Journal of Statistical Software, Vol. 18, Issue 2, Jan 2007 for more information.

There is some more information at http://mevik.net/work/software/pls.html